# Spacy Rule-Based Matching outputs undesired phrase bit

Tags: python, nlp, spacy-3

I was reproducing a Spacy rule-matching example:

```
import spacy 
from spacy.matcher import Matcher 

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")
doc = nlp("Good morning, I'm here. I'll say good evening!!")
pattern = [{"LOWER": "good"},{"LOWER": {"IN": ["morning", "evening"]}},{"IS_PUNCT": True}] 
matcher.add("greetings", [pattern]) # good morning/evening with one pattern with the help of IN as follows
matches = matcher(doc)
for mid, start, end in matches:
    print(start, end, doc[start:end])
```

which is supposed to match

```
Good morning  good evening!
```

But the above code also matches "I" in both occasions

```
0 3 Good morning,
3 4 I
7 8 I
10 13 good evening!
```

I just want to remove the "I" from the Matching

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code on my machine (`Windows 11 64-bit`, `Python 3.10.9`, `spaCy 3.4.4` with both the `en_core_web_sm` and `en_core_web_trf` pipelines), it produces a `NameError` because `matcher` is not defined. After defining `matcher` as an instantiation of the `Matcher` class in accordance with the [spaCy Matcher documentation](https://spacy.io/api/matcher), I get the following (desired) output with both pipelines:

```
0 3 Good morning,
10 13 good evening!
```

The full working code is shown below. I'd suggest restarting your IDE and/or computer if you're still seeing your unexpected results.

```py
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("Good morning, I'm here. I'll say good evening!!")
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
pattern = [{"LOWER": "good"}, {"LOWER": {"IN": ["morning", "evening"]}}, {"IS_PUNCT": True}]
matcher.add("greetings", [pattern])  # good morning/evening with one pattern with the help of IN as follows
matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    print(start, end, doc[start:end])
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, probably I was stacking many examples in a single sheet so the variables were mixing up.

Comment: @Aureon I suspected that was the case, I've had similar issues before. Glad the answer helped identify the problem.